# Getting Apple Cinema HD Display working in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, driver, cinema-display

Does anyone have any experience trying to get an Apple Cinema HD Display working in Windows 7 x64? Note: This isn't for a Bootcamped Mac, it's for a Dell XPS Laptop.

Is this even possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is still relevant, in my case for a shuttle barebone and two 24" cinema displays. works but without sound. micro works fine, though!

Answer (score 8):

This question is old, but in case anyone is still looking, a driver that works is here:

http://www.holstschumacher.dk/p/brightness-controller.html

Look for the link to [Beta Versions and Old Releases](https://bitbucket.org/Gensplejs/publicfiles/downloads/) for the latest.

The beta version works with Windows 10 Creators update as of 12/25/2017.

Comment: Worked for me (Shuttle Barebone PC with two 24" Cinema Displays. Showed two monitor, I could change brightness, but it crashed at some point. Also, Windows 10 is not able to give Sound through the displays - for now I have to use a headset.

Comment: I have a 24 and a 27 inch LED both work with this answer I also have sound through both on Windows 10 pro. This should be the accepted answer. It worked perfectly once I went to the downloads section and got the latest. The link for the download did not work however. it is version 1.4.4 and it requires dotnet4.5 My system has 4.5 and 4.8 but it refused to install. The latest on the site as of this comment is 1.5.110 and worked immediately for both monitors connected to a Radeon HD 7770 Ghz edition on a Dell r730xd server.

Comment: I stated wrong file version previously, I was seeing numbers from a file under it on my drive. The correct number is 1.5.7 Beta

Answer (score 2):

[This article over on the Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4273)  has links to some driver/software updates for Windows 7, but the drivers are from Bootcamp 3.2

This is the direct link to the [Bootcamp drivers for x64](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL979).

Even though you are not running a Mac, the Bootcamp drivers will install regardless.

Bootcamp 4 is however available for [download](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) (for OSX users only)
You should be able to extract the drivers and install them separately, 7-Zip will allow you to extract from DMGs and PKGs

Note, the display should be detected on all machines, however you may have issues with brigthness controls, or using the built in audio without using the Apple drivers.

Comment: Thanks for this! One question: I cannot find the link to download Bootcamp 4?

Comment: Also, is there a problem with Bootcamp 3.3 that made you select Bootcamp 3.2? http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1443

Comment: not at all, the only KB article I could find a reference to drivers for the Cinema Display specifically were for 3.2 - Bootcamp 4 is only downloadable if you have OSX, you will have to source the download elsewhere if you don't have a Mac

Comment: I have a Mac, I'm currently writing to you from it, but I can't see the link :-/

Comment: Do you have the Bootcamp assistant in /Applications/Utilities  ? if you do, run that everything else is downloaded from there.

Comment: Everything I tried with bootcamp drivers installed a ton of unneeded garbage and still did not work. I tried everything from 3.0 to 3.3. The answer above this worked like a charm without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I use the WinACD drivers from sourceforge.net for my dell laptop connected to my apple cinema display.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/winacd/files/WinACD/WinACD-0.4/

Comment: Was not able to install. Installer said it got interrupted (at ca. 80%). Maybe the interruption was the dialog for administrator access.

Answer (score 1):

## Update 2021

1. Boot Camp drivers

   - The official Apple BootCamp 5 (Windows 7/8) Drivers are here:

     - https://support.apple.com/downloads/bootcamp-windows-10 \
   - The Boot Camp 6 (Windows 10) Drivers are mirrored here:

     - https://download.digiex.net/Drivers/Bootcamp/AppleBcUpdate6.0.6171-01.April.2016.zip
2. Get the latest version (probably still [5.1.5769](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) since it hasn't been updated since 2015).
3. Extract the files to `C:\Drivers` or some such
4. Search `PowerShell` in the Windows Bar and alt-click to reveal **Run as Administrator**
5. Go into the Drivers directory, probably something like

   ```
   pushd C:\Drivers\bootcamp5.1.5769\BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\
   ```
6. Install BootCamp:

   ```
   msiexec /install BootCamp.msi
   ```
7. Reboot
8. Reboot again
9. Pray
10. Maybe it works now, if you've got the right chipsets and fully supported motherboard, etc.

(but it probably still won't work because USB 3 and Thunderbolt 1/2/3 etc have really bad cross device and cross platform compatibility - [because reasons](https://xkcd.com/927/))

Answer (score 0):

Here are my experiences with using a Cinema HD on a non apple system. Not a full solution but it is something.

An Apple Cinema HD display should work on any system that has a DVI-D port. For the 30" and the 27" you will need a dual-link DVI-D port to be able to use the full resolution. I have had mine (a 30") on several systems without problems.

Without drivers, brightness controls on the screen, usb hub and firewire hub should all work. Can only confirm working of brightness and usb-hub myself as I have never had it connected to a PC with firewire. Caveat with brightness is that you won't get the nice brightness setting overlay as this is done in software by OSX.

If you want to have a brightness overlay, you will need a bootcamp CD and don't forget to connect the USB connector of your screen to your system as the brightness controls go over USB.

The drivers are in:

```
32-bit: D:\Drivers\Apple\AppleDisplayInstaller.exe
64-bit: D:\Drivers\Apple\x64\AppleDisplayInstaller.exe
```

This driver will give you a HID driver for the display which is only half of what you need. You also need to install the bootcamp utility:

```
32-bit: D:\Drivers\Apple\BootCamp.msi
64-bit: D:\Drivers\Apple\BootCamp64.msi
```

After installation and reboot you will get a bootcamp icon in your tray. When you change the brightness of the screen using the controls on the screen your system should now display an overlay. Unfortunatly I haven't succeeded yet in getting into the configuration of the bootcamp utility because it complaints about the startup disk.

There are some settings you could try to tinker with in the registry at

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Apple Inc.\CinemaDisplay
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Apple Inc.\Brightness
```

Comment: Did sound work? My Monitors work and in the Windows 10 setting are shown with moving bars, so sound is channeled to them but they don't make any noise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got the brighness controls to work, in 2018, on an Apple Cinema Display.

The existing guides on this page were a little aged (doing this in 2018), so I looked [elsewhere](https://duntuk.com/how-install-apple-thunderbolt-display-non-apple-thunderbolt-pc-brightness-control-support) (blog post from 2014).

Installed BootCamp 5.0.5033 using those instructions, but seems also [5.1.5769](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=fi_FI&locale=fi_FI) is available. Note: No macOS device was needed to fetch the packages.

Notes:

- Installation reset my PC's Clock for some reason (messed the timezones); easy to fix manually, though
- Installation reset my PC's C:\ drive name to "BOOTCAMP". I changed it back.

The diamond Bootcamp control did *not* show up immediately. I ran Apple Software Update just in case. Rebooted. Still nothing. An *extra* reboot after that seemed to do the trick.. I.e. if you don't see it, reboot one more time. :)

---

Would I recommend this? Maybe not.

Following those instructions (`msiexec /i BootCamp.msi`) installs so much Apple ware on the PC that I might try to get them out. Also changing the brightness via the diamond is clumsy (Fn+F1, Fn+F2 don't seem to work).