# Can I use the built-in camera of my Apple Cinema Display on Windows 10

Tags: display, windows, camera, cinema-display

I have a 27" Apple Cinema Display (non Thunderbolt) working fine on Windows 10, except for the built-in camera that is not being recognized. Is there any way to activate it or any drivers that I can download that can make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Apple Cinema HD Display working in Windows 7 x64](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/getting-apple-cinema-hd-display-working-in-windows-7-x64)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. The problem was that although I had connected the monitor to my laptop using the mini display port, I had not plugged in the USB cable. The camera on the Apple cinema display needs the USB connection in order to be recognized and start working. I connected the USB cable from the monitor to my laptop, and everything works well.